# Can we use state in arrow(functional) modules react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm passing settings screen to TabNavigator in my App. Can we use states in this type of export?

```
export default ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
            style={styles.itemStyle}
            title="Log Out"
            onPress={() => onSignOut().then(() => navigation.navigate("SignedOut"))}
        />
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Please read this [link](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

Comment: functional components do not have states. You need to make it a class component in order for it to have states.

Comment: @lavish I was thinking it as a short form of declaring components. Functional is the word. I came to know they are stateless +1 I'm not sure should I delete the question, or keep it for another newb?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926574/react-functional-components-vs-classical-components

answers in this question have explained it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use state concept only in the class which extends Component{react}.
Module is stateless

Comment: To be more informative arrow components have only props. They are called `Stateless Functional Components`.