# Class based component vs Functional components what is the difference ( Reactjs )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to **React** and I want to have a clear idea of which one to use, when it comes to components I get to see there are two types.

**Functional Component :**

```
import React from 'react'

const userInput = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange={props.nameChanged} value={props.username}></input>
        </div>
    )
};

export default userInput;
```

**Class based component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';
import UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Assignment Output :</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <UserOutput 
            username={this.state.Usernames[0].username}>
            Welcome to React!
            </UserOutput>
            <UserInput 
            nameChanged={this.nameChangedHandler}>
            </UserInput>
          </li>
                      </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get to read that we should always try to use a **Functional component** because it helps in some things and also heard that we should avoid using a **Class based component** as much as possible.

I am confused which is right and which is not.

Why should try to use Functional component where ever its possible, what are the benefits ?

When should we go for a Functional component and when not, is not clear.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN thanks, that actually answered my question.

Comment: I found answer for question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926574/react-functional-components-vs-classical-components Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Class Components**

- Class-based Components uses ES6 class syntax. It can make use of the lifecycle methods.
- As you can see in the example that u have given above Class components extend from React.Component.
- In here you have to use this keyword to access the props and functions that you declare inside the class components.

**Functional Components**

- Functional Components are simpler comparing to class-based functions.
- Functional Components mainly focuses on the UI of the application, not on the behavior.
- To be more precise these are basically render function in the class
  component.
- Functional Components can't have state (without hooks) and they can't make
  use of lifecycle methods.

Comment: Refer this link https://medium.com/@tejassavaliya/functional-components-vs-class-components-in-react-507db6a47439

Comment: Your answer is no longer valid, you can use hooks to manage state, context and mount/unmount lifecycles.