# React-Native: When to use Class- or Functional-Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I am pretty new to **react/react-native** and want to develope my first app. During programming I saw that there are two diffrent ways to declare a component. As I understood I always have to use class-components, if I want to access state variables. But according to the react documentations it is also possible to access state variables via useState inside functional-components and now I do not rly know what to use as best practice.

Is there some sort of **rule set or coding patterns** on **when to use class- and when functional-components**?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: functional components + hooks is the "suggested" way, but you can still use class components, it's not like that's wrong

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926574/react-functional-components-vs-classical-components) should answer your question.