# Dfferent between class based components and functional based component

Tags: reactjs

I know there are endless Questions and Answers about this, but everyone are talking about the code and the syntax.

what I'm asking is that what is the different between class based and functional based components, when it comes to performance, rendering, state managements and ...

should we use class based components at all or not.

Comment: read basics: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926574/react-functional-components-vs-classical-components

Answer (score 0):

> Functional Components

In functional components, you need to export the default function `export default function component() {}` `return` to render content on the page and you can use `React Hooks` easily without worrying about `this keyword`

**Example:-**

```
export default function App () {
     const [count , setCount ] = useState(0)
     useEffect (()=> { 
      // start 
     } , [])
     useEffect (()=> { 
      // update 
     } , [])
     return (
       <> jsx </>
     )
}
```

> Class Base Components

In class base components first, you have to inherit your class from
`React.Component`. Class Base Components use `render` function to render
content on the page. if you wana to use `React Hooks` its syntax is little bit
different than `functional components` and you also have to add the `this`
keyword with every variable

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
 
  constructor (props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = { count : 0 }
    // this.setState( {count : this.state.count })
  }

  // useEffect Syntax

  componentDidMount() {
   // start
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
   // do update
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    // on destory
  }

  render () {
    return ( <> JSX </> )
  }

}
```